# Can't work with data obtained with $.Ajax()

Tags: javascript, ajax, couchdb

I am writing a JS where I want to make some Ajax calls to get a JSON file from my DB in CouchDB. My code is based on examples I found online, but my lack of experience and knowledge is making it difficult to fix it completely.

My code:

```
function myFunction(){

var request = $.ajax({

    url:'http://admin:pass@localhost:5984/db/_design/view/_view/view',
    type:'get',
    dataType:'json'

});

request.done (function (data)){

    var result;
    for (var i in data){
        if( data[i] == key){
            result.push(data[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(result);
};}
```

Problem: It seems like it is not even doing the requested call since when I try to print my array it isn`t doing anything.

The way see it, in the first part where I defined *request* it should get the JSON file from CouchDB. And, if correct, in the second part where the request is done *request.done* I give the function how I want the JSON file to be taken care of. To make it clear, my idea is to iterate through the data and to save the values of the "key" in every row in my result-array.

Comment: add `cache:false` to your ajax method

Comment: There is an extra `)` on the line `request.done (function (data)){`. Does removing it do anything?

Comment: Also, `key` is not defined